# Is there a subscriptable python map?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for a data structure and I was wondering if it was implemented in the python library (I could not find it on google…) :

is there an object that acts like a map, but is subscriptable (and does not copy the data)

ie is there a function that takes a subscriptable object `input` and a function `f`, and returns a subscriptable object `output` such as,

- forall i where `input[i]` does not raise an exception  , `output[i] == f(input[i])` equals true
- otherwise, `output[i]` raises an exception
- `len(output) == len(input)`

In order to, for example, do this :

```
r = subscriptable_map( lambda x: x+1, range(10) )
assert(r[0] == 1)
```

Does it exist in the python library, or should I implement it myself ?

Comment: Why not just use a function?  `r = lambda x: x+1; assert r(0) == 1`?

Comment: Can you please explain why the standard python `map` doesn't work for this? This would do what you show `r={ i:i+1 for i in range(10)}`. But, in this case, a list is even better: `r = list(range(1,11))`.

Comment: The standard python map, in this example, would raise "TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable

Comment: This is a little underspecified. The reason the object returned from `map` is not subscriptable it because it is an iterator that's lazily evaluated. What should `r[9]` do? Run the iterations to item 9 and then return value? Cache those values? Calculate them in a non-lazy way (that would just be calling list on the map).

Comment: @Mark Meyer : it should call range(10)[9] and apply the lambda on that (basically use __getitem__() and not __iter__())

Comment: @Scott I wanted it to act like a list …  no worries tho, if it doesn’t exist i’ll implement it

Comment: If it should act like a list, you may as well make it a list up front. `list(map(..., range(10)))`.

Comment: @chepner, except making a new list copies all the data

Comment: Anything you do that bypasses earlier elements of the input iterable has to do that anyway. That was Mark Meyer's point. True, using a list immediately may prematurely cache all the elements after the 9th one. Which again, is why Mark called your question underspecified. We don't know enough about how you will use `r` to assess the impact of caching or discarding elements you retrieve while trying to reach the subscripted element.

Comment: Sorry if it wasnt clear, the input should not be an iterable (as you said, it makes no sense), it should be a subscriptable object. I’ll edit the question

Comment: @chepner I’ve edited the question, is it better ?

Comment: Much better, and I agree with your accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know of no such built-in.  You could roll your own though with a class and magic methods though.

```
class SubscriptableMap(object):
    def __init__(self, f, subscriptable):
        self.f = f
        self.subscriptable = subscriptable
    def __getitem__(self, x): #subscripting
        return self.f(self.subscriptable[x])
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.subscriptable)

m = SubscriptableMap(lambda x: x+1, range(10))
print(len(m))
print(m[0])
print(m[20])
```

Note well that the second argument here needs itself to be indexable, which excludes most lazily evaluated iterators.

Comment: Thank you, I think that’s what I’ll do !

Answer (score 0):

It is something like this

```py
r = list(map(lambda x: x+1, range(10)))
```

So we can do it like this

```py
from itertools import repeat

SubscriptableMap = lambda *args:list(map(*args))

m = SubscriptableMap(lambda x: x+1, range(10))
print(len(m))   # 10
print(m[0])     # 1
# print(m[20])    # IndexError: list index out of range

text = 'Know someone who can answer?'
m = SubscriptableMap(str.__mul__, text.split(), repeat(3))
print(m)
# ['KnowKnowKnow', 'someonesomeonesomeone', 'whowhowho', 'cancancan',
#  'answer?answer?answer?']
```